# page refresh when using submit button

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I using the html page with validation . But when i click the input submit button page was refreshed.  But how to restrict the refresh the page . My sample code is:

```
<div >

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.1)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.1, new { @id = "student", @class = "test" })

               <input type="submit" value="click valid" onclick="button();" />

             <div> <span style="color:Red"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.1) </span>
             </div>

         </div>
```

Comment: MVC Validation needs the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` javascript file to be referenced on your views.

also, make sure you add the required `DataAnnotations` to your corresponding Model.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false;` at the end of your `button()` function.

Comment: but its not validate data,its pass the empty value to controller goes to the another step

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
<input type="submit" value="click valid" onclick="button();" />
```

This

```
<input type="button" value="click valid" onclick="button();" />
```

Because using input type=submit submits the form and we cant prevent page refreshing.But using input type=button and in your `onclick` function submit the form using javascript function `form.submit`.So the page will get refreshed and submitted if all validations are passed

Comment: using button its validate the data?

Comment: type="button" not validate the data